# cleaning deleted documents from solr index

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm using solr on my website but I have small problem. Indexing works great.

I've deleted a few documents from my database (I had 50 documents now I have 41). I've started dataimport, solr tells that he indexed 41 documents (great), deleted 0 (strange). The problem is that I can still search the deleted documents. Why is that? I used `clean=true` but it didn't change anything.

How can I delete from the index documents that don't exist?

Comment: It isn't so clear if you're deleting documents through dih `clean=true` parameters or manually.

Comment: sorry but I don`t understand you. I`ve deleted document in my database from my CMS. Now i want to reindex data but I don`t want to have documents that I`ve already deleted. I will add that by document I mean record in my DB. I`m indexing data from my DB

Answer (score 1):

Weird. DataImportHandler with `clean=true` should work out for your need. 
An alternative with the benefit of avoiding to stress and eventually messing up the live solr instance is to swap: you create a new index B without touching the live one (say A). B is created from scratch, so will be completely synchronized with your db! 
Ones that B is created just launch `.../admin/cores/?action=SWAP&core=A&other=B` and the job is done!
I'm doing it with a 1M docs index on Solr 3.5 and works well.